# Similar sum of squares in GLM

Tags: regression, linear-model, sums-of-squares

I have run the General Linear Model in SPSS to analyse the effect of several demographic variables (e.g. gender, age) on the relationship between X and Y.

So essentially, this is an analysis to see if there is a significant interaction between (for example) age and X on Y. (Also called moderator effect)

I have found that there is a significant interaction for all the demographic variables (which makes practical sense in the context of my study).

When I look at the Type III Sum of Squares output, I get the following:

- For Gender*X: 143.341
- For Age*X: 142.879
- For Education*X: 144.345

I was told that this is a bit 'unusual' because they are so close. (Unfortunately, I could not fully understand why this was unusual!)

**Question 1: Why is this result unusual? What does this mean?**

In addition, I have discussed that if I test the same interaction in multiple regression, the t statistics is not significant but the f statistics in General Linear Model is significant?

**Question 2: Why is this the case?**

Comment: How are you coding age and education?  As continuous variables or as class indicators?  If the latter, what classes are used?  Concerning these interactions, what do the scatterplots (or boxplots, as appropriate) indicate?

Comment: Gender is 1 = male and 2 = female. Age is 1 = Under 18 years, 2 = 18 to 45 years and 3 = Over 45 years. Education is 1 = Up to Year 12 and 2 = Post Year 12. The scatter plots show a positive relationship.

Comment: Adhesh, it is difficult to answer unless you indicate your model. Give the SPSS syntax of your procedure.

Comment: The point of my question, Adhesh, which I should have made more clearly, is that there is a difference between using these values as if they were continuous variables and using them as categorical variables.  I suspect you might be treating the codes as actual numbers (continuous variables).  That would make most of your interactions next to meaningless and could explain why they give similar results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The type III sum of squares show how much the sum of squared errors (SSQE) would be reduced if you added the relevant term, e.g., Gender * X, to a model that already had all the other terms in it.  What makes your result unusual is that there isn't any reason to expect that adding, for example, Gender * X to a model that already had Gender, Age, Education, X, Age*X, and Education*X would improve the model by essentially the same amount as adding Education*X to a model that already had Gender, Age, Education, X, Gender*X, and Age*X.  And this happened with three terms!  It makes me wonder if Gender, Age, and Education aren't very highly correlated given X, but if they were, having two of the __*X interactions in the model would cause adding the third interaction to make very little improvement to the model, I would expect.
2. I'm not altogether sure what the question is, but I'll take a shot at it anyway.  The t-test in multiple linear regression is based on simultaneously estimating all the coefficients, then calculating the t-test based on those estimates.  The F test for the type III SSQE is based on estimating all the coefficients except the one being tested, then adding the one being tested to the model and looking at how much it improves it - a sequential procedure rather than a simultaneous procedure.  You could think of it as regressing the term to be tested against the residuals from the model with all the other terms in it, which obviously will give different, and sometimes seemingly contradictory, results from a process where the term to be tested is just included in the model along with all the other terms (unless the term to be tested is orthogonal to all the other terms in the model, in which case you'd get the same results.)

Answer (score 3):

@Adhesh I think, looking over your many questions, that you are getting bad advice from somewhere off this list, then coming here and asking about it. Maybe this is coming from a bad book (or more than one) or from a person who knows a little bit about statistics, but not a lot.

In any case, if you tell us what you want to learn about, perhaps some of us could suggest some better books and sources.

As to your question - the only reason this seems unusual to me is for the same reason it would be unusual if you met two other people and both were named Adhesh.  It's a coincidence and coincidences are, by definition, unusual